# What is the easiest way to save a String on a server

Tags: java, linux, server

I created a game and now I want to add a global highscore. I want to save the highscore on my server. I think the easiest way is to overwrite a textfile on my server that stores the scores and the names of the top players. How can I do this? The game is not running on my server! It is running on the client side.

Comment: So the question is how you write a string to a file? Did you research that already?

Comment: you could also just create a class `Highscore` and make it `Serializable`. Or use a database.

Comment: I know how to write a file but i dont know how to store it on a server.

Comment: you should clarify in your question that the game is not running on your server, right?

Comment: sorry I forgot to specify that the game is not running on a server.

Comment: Send the highscore to the server (e.g. via webservices) and let the server handle the file writing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of writing a string to a file using the `java.nio.file.Files` class:

```
try {
    String hightscore = "MyString";
    Files.write(new File("D:/temp/file.txt").toPath(), hightscore.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I need to save the score on a server.

Comment: well then there are a lot of answers for that, you could communicate with a webservice the server publishes, upload a hightscore file through FTP, maybe your server is running a DBMS which you can connect to....

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a flat file like flavio.donze did or you can use a database.

So there is usually no relevance if you want to save it one the server or somewhere else. The path decides the location.

If you want to upload the scores from a client to a server, you can use multiple solutions.

F.e. adding per RMI or Webservice call

Comment: no the game is not executed on the server. It is executed on a local machine of the user.

Comment: Try using a webservice like REST
my-server-path/add/score | put 

something simple like that

Answer (score 0):

You can hire a simple hosting PHP/MySql and save the score in a database.

```
try { 
    URL url = new URL("http://exemple.com/saveScore.php");

    InputStream is = url.openStream();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

    String response = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : null;

    if (response == "ok") {
        System.out.println("Saved!");
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In **saveScore.php**, after you save, just print ok.

```
<?php

// DB OPERATIONS

echo "ok";
exit;
```